# systemd service fle: Restart=on-failure not allowed for Type=oneshot services

Tags: linux, systemd

I created a systemd service file to run two rsync commands sequentially and I need to retry until successful. Sometimes the rsync server is down. Systemd tells me Restart=on-failure is not allowed for Type=oneshot services. What other Type of service can I use?

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -atvzq --no-owner --no-group --delete rsync://(some address) /srv/www/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -atvzq --no-owner --no-group --delete rsync://(some address) /srv/www1/
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're only using `Type=oneshot` so you can have several `ExecStart=` commands.   Other than that, there is no reason to use `Type=oneshot` since you don't seem to have services that are triggered on successful activation and you aren't using `RemainAfterExit=true`

Instead, use `Type=simple` and use `ExecStartPre=`

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rsync -atvzq --no-owner --no-group --delete rsync://(some address) /srv/www/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -atvzq --no-owner --no-group --delete rsync://(some address) /srv/www1/
```

Here is what will happen:

1. `ExecStartPre=` will run before the `ExecStart=` command.
2. During `ExecStartPre=` execution, the unit will be "activating"
3. If `ExecStartPre=` fails, `ExecStart=` will not run, the unit will be considered "failed" and will restart.
4. During `ExecStart=` execution, the unit will be "activated"
5. After `ExecStart=` finishes, the unit will be "inactive (dead)" if everything was successful or "failed" if either command was unsuccessful.

If you want to ignore the failure of `ExecStartPre=` and force `ExecStart=` to run, prefix the `ExecStartPre=` command with a `-` to ignore the non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, try to use two services A and B, where B depends on A and A is a oneshot service.

With the set-up shown in the example below, service B is pulled in when the multi-user target is reached (or any other target you specify in the [Install] section). Service B won't start before service A because it has a dependency on service A and is set to start after service A. Also, service B will wait for service A to terminate due to service A being type oneshot.

Because service A is requisite to service B, service B will fail to start if service A fails. Should service B fail, it will restart. Note that default settings put a limit on how many unsuccessful restart attempts (in a given time interval) are allowed before systemd will stop any further attempts to restart.

**B.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync Task B Service
Requisite=A.service
After=A.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -atvzq --no-owner --no-group --delete rsync://(some address) /srv/www/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**A.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Sync Task A Service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync -atvzq --no-owner --no-group --delete rsync://(some address) /srv/www/
```